# Jsf2: How to add a submenu to menu model in primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a toolbar that contain a dynamic menu item. I want to add submenu to this menu item:

```
<p:toolbar>
   <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
       <p:menuButton model="#{menuBean.menuModel}" value="Item1"/>
       <p:separator/>
       <p:commandButton value="Item2" ajax="false"/>
   </p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
```

I'm using a menumodel. but this dont show the submenus.

```
String[] menus = {"Two", "Three"};
String[] items = {"1", "2"};

menuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
DefaultMenuItem one = new DefaultMenuItem("One");
menuModel.addElement(jobsItem);
for (String s : menue) {
  DefaultSubMenu m = new DefaultSubMenu(s);
  for (String i : items) {
    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem(i);
    m.addElement(item);
  }    
  menuModel.addElement(m);
}
```

when i change the p:menuButton to p:menu i can see submenus but i want to use menubutton...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p:menuButton` does not support `MenuModel`.

you can't.

P.S.

you can do it with a `p:commandButton` and a overlay `p:menu`:

```
<p:commandButton id="dynaButton" value="Show" type="button" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>  
<p:menu model="#{menuBean.model}" overlay="true" trigger="dynaButton" my="left top" at="left bottom" />
```

Comment: thx. It works. I just change your p:menu to p:tierdmenu and everything is OK.